# Prove that:$\lim_{M\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{M}(-1)^k{M\choose k}{{\ln{(x+k)!}}\over (k+x-1)(k+x)}={\ln{x!}\over x(1-x)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, binomial-coefficients, euler-mascheroni-constant

Show that

Where $\gamma=0.5772156...$;Euler's constant

$x>1$; it is an integer

$$\lim_{M\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{M}(-1)^k{M\choose k}{{\ln{((x+k)!)}}\over (k+x-1)(k+x)}={\ln{x!}\over x(1-x)}\tag1$$

and setting $x=1$, show that also

$$\lim_{M\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{M}(-1)^k{M\choose k}{{\ln{((k+1)!)}}\over k(k+1)}=\gamma-1\tag2$$

Why is $(2)$ converges to $\gamma-1$?

I try: not a clue where to start. Any hints or show the way, please. Thank you.

I used a sum calculator and experiment with $(2)$ and got the following results

${1\over k}-{1\over 1+k}={1\over k(1+k)}$

$$\lim_{M\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{M}(-1)^k{M\choose k}{{\ln{((k+1)!)}}\over k}=\gamma-1$$

$$\lim_{M\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{M}(-1)^k{M\choose k}{{\ln{((k+1)!)}}\over k+1}=0$$

Comment: Is $x$ integer?

Comment: Are you sure that there is still $x$ in (2), in the numerator? It seem to me it should be $k+1$

Comment: For the (2), it seem to me somewhat possible to show with the following identity. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/660775/euler-mascheroni-constant-understanding-why-lim-m-rightarrow-infty-sum-n?rq=1  .  Just replace the right side of your expression, with the series given. And combine them under same limit and same sum. (though we haven't shown that your series are convergent). I hope it will help.

Comment: By $\ln(x+1)!$, do you mean $\ln((x+1)!)$, or $(\ln(x+1))!$?

Comment: $$
\lim_{x\rightarrow1}\frac{\log(x!)}{x(1-x)} = \lim_{x\rightarrow1}\frac{\log(x!)}{x} + \lim_{x\rightarrow1}\frac{\log(x!)}{1-x} = \lim_{x\rightarrow1}\frac{\log\left(\Gamma(x+1)\right)}{1-x} \\ = \lim_{x\rightarrow1}\frac{d/dx\left[\,\log\left(\Gamma(x+1)\right)\,\right]}{d/dx\left[\,1-x\,\right]} = -\lim_{x\rightarrow1}\,\psi(x+1) = -\psi(2) = \gamma - 1
$$